# Classifying DEM according to elevation in R?

Tags: raster, r, dem, reclassify

```
 r<-raster("DEM.tif")
```

How to do the classification based on every ten meters for example and have different colors too?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `reclassify` function in the [raster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) package to reclassify the DEM.  The general idea is to generate a reclass matrix which provides the instructions on how to reclassify the continuous DEM elevation values.

---

### [image]

```
require(rgdal)
require(raster)

# Read DEM and convert to raster layer object
dem = raster("C:/temp/dem.tif")

# Generate a reclass matrix (begin, end, value ...)
m = c(290, 300, 1, 300, 310, 2, 310, 320, 3, 320, 330, 4, 330, 340, 5)
rclmat = matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

# Reclassify the raster layer
reclassified_dem = reclassify(dem, rclmat)

# plot the results
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(dem)
plot(reclassified_dem)

# Write to disk
writeRaster(reclassified_dem, "C:/temp/out_dem.tif", drivername = "GTiff", type = "Float32")
```

Comment: very nice,since i'm a beginner explain how you managed to plot 2 things without adding add=T in the second? I guess something with the par happens? Also tell me how you zoom in at a certain point of the map in both the split images

Comment: `par` is used to set graphic properties.  In this case, I specified that I want to plot two figures in a 1 row X 2 column arrangement.  The map is not zoomed in--it is the entire extent of my DEM.

Comment: the "write to disk line" what exactly does?exports it? or maybe takes it from memory to disk?if yes what does it mean practically?

Comment: Note that I have altered the script to make it easier to understand.  The `# Write to disk` line takes a RasterLayer class (i.e. `reclassified_dem`) which is available only in memory and writes it to your hard drive as a geotiff.  You can then use the geotiff in your choice of GISs.

Comment: Therefore exports it correct?Why didn't we set location directory for the saved file?

Comment: Export is another way saying write to disk.  I explicitly hardcoded the output path and name `"C:/temp/out_dem.tif"`, therefore, there is no need to set the location directory (i.e. it is already in the path).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23259/discussion-between-gsa-and-aaron).

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative using the function `cut` to assign elevation values into classes of elevation, making possible to discretize colors in the map (color per class of elevation).

```
#Generate reproducible example
library(raster)
f = system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster") #path to raster file
DEM = raster(f) #import raster file
DEM = rasterToPoints(DEM) #change raster to matrix object with coordinates
DEM = data.frame(DEM) #change matrix to data.frame object

#assign the DEM elevation values to class intervals
DEM$test = cut(DEM$test,breaks=c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1500)) #here you'll want to create classes with intervals of 10 meters.

#Plot raster
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
geom_tile(data=DEM,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=test)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer("Elevation (m)", type = "seq", palette = "Greys") +
  xlab("Meters") + ylab("Meters") +
  coord_equal() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border=element_rect(color="black"),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 14, vjust=+0.7),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size = 14, vjust=-0.2),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size = 11),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size = 11),
        legend.title=element_text(size = 13),
        legend.text=element_text(size = 13))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice approach and it is always nice to see `ggplot` figures!